# Firebase Analytics violates Google Privacy Policy

Tags: android, firebase

In my app I have implemented Firebase Analytics to collect events. Tw days ago I received e-mail from Google that my app is investigated because of policy privacy. Here's the message :

```
Your app is using the XXX SDK, which is uploading user’s installed packages information without a prominent disclosure.
```

I checked and the SDK that adds permission :

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

is Firebase Analytics. Unfortunately Google doesn't want to help me by providing info how can I solve this which is strange cause Firebase is Google product , right ? So my question is : how can I remove this permission without removing Firebase , and second - do you think that if I update my privacy policy with specific info about Firebase it will be enough ?

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Check if other dependencies that you use don't violate policy rules :) In my case - that was the problem.